# Remove all columns with no data from DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable

If all the items for a particular column are empty, I want to remove that column from the DataTable.  What's the most elegant way to do this operation on all columns in the DataTable?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use the [`Compute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute.aspx) method, like this:

```
if (table.Compute("COUNT(ColumnName)", "ColumnName <> NULL") == 0)
    table.Columns.Remove("ColumnName");
```

Alternatively, you can use LINQ:

```
if (table.AsEnumerable().All(dr => dr.IsNull("ColumnName")))
    table.Columns.Remove("ColumnName");
```

---

**EDIT**: To completely answer the question:

```
foreach(var column in table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToArray()) {
    if (table.AsEnumerable().All(dr => dr.IsNull(column)))
        table.Columns.Remove(column);
}
```

You need to call `ToArray` because the loop will modify the collection.

Comment: Nice.  Adjust code to check all the column names and you get the green checkmark.

Comment: Maybe ;-).  I've actually implemented it myself already.  Just don't want to mark it correct yet since it doesn't completely answer the initial question.

Comment: My DataTable Have many rows.One of the row contain One specific strint Like=”Container”.I want to delete all of the above rows of the container string ,Can you plz show some syntax .

Answer (score 2):

```
private static void RemoveUnusedColumnsAndRows(DataTable table)
    {            
        for (int h = 0; h < table.Rows.Count; h++)
        {
            if (table.Rows[h].IsNull(0) == true)
            {
                table.Rows[h].Delete();
            }
            enter code here
        }
        table.AcceptChanges();
        foreach (var column in table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToArray())
        {
            if (table.AsEnumerable().All(dr => dr.IsNull(column)))
                table.Columns.Remove(column);
        }
        table.AcceptChanges();           
    }
```

Comment: This will remove a row if its first column has a null value. It should check all columns in that row, something like ```            foreach (var row in table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToArray())
            {
                if (row.ItemArray.All(field => field is DBNull || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(field as string)))
                    table.Rows.Remove(row);
            }```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void RemoveNullColumnFromDataTable(DataTable dt)
{
    for (int i = dt.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (dt.Rows[i][1] == DBNull.Value)
            dt.Rows[i].Delete();
    }
    dt.AcceptChanges();
}
```

Comment: Surely this deletes the entire row if column 1 in that row is DBNULL. Not quite what the OP was after.

Answer (score 0):

```
Function RemoveEmptyColumns(Datatable As DataTable) As Boolean
    Dim mynetable As DataTable = Datatable.Copy
    Dim counter As Integer = mynetable.Rows.Count
    Dim col As DataColumn
    For Each col In mynetable.Columns
        Dim dr() As DataRow = mynetable.Select(col.ColumnName + " is   Null ")
        If dr.Length = counter Then
            Datatable.Columns.Remove(col.ColumnName)
            Datatable.AcceptChanges()
        End If
    return true
end function
```

Answer (score 0):

You clear all column in datatable.you use like that.

datatable.Columns.Clear();

Comment: This clears all the column which is not what the user is asking for.