# how to remove empty columns of Data Table if it doesn't have column name, and index of column is dynamic in c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, uipath

> I trried to use below code, but it requires Column name or index

```
DataTable t;
t.Columns.Remove("columnName");
t.Columns.RemoveAt(columnIndex);
```

Comment: which line do you want to remove?

Comment: if its the only empty one maybe this helps
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766902/remove-all-columns-with-no-data-from-datatable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove all columns with no data from DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766902/remove-all-columns-with-no-data-from-datatable)

Answer (score 2):

You just need a loop to verify... Something like this:

```
foreach(var column in t.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToArray()) {
    if (t.AsEnumerable().All(dr => dr.IsNull(column)))
        t.Columns.Remove(column);
}
```

Credits: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766902/remove-all-columns-with-no-data-from-datatable)